# How to create a folder inside another folder with uid included firebase storage

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to create this structure in Storage

Documents>FolderwithUID>Received

I have this

```
 var uid="F1RFw3FVAO3FJ8ORrf7oJPyR13z";
 var storageRef = storage.ref('User Documents/`${uid}`/Received');
```

how would i include that uid in the path. Right now it just creates a folder named uid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not doing string interpolation correctly for JavaScript.  Perhaps you mean to write this:

```
storageRef = storage.ref(`User Documents/${uid}/Received`);
```

Or even better, let the SDK build the path components for you:

```
storageRef = storage.ref('/').child('User Documents').child(uid).child('Received');
```

Comment: The second one is what I was aiming for actually. Awesome